# ExecutorService with Task chain shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

I have an `ExecutorService` which executes tasks which itself submit new tasks to the ExecutorService.

When I call `.shutdown()`, I want the running tasks still being able to submit new tasks to the ExecutorService which need to be finished. But I don't want to be able to submit new tasks from outside to the `ExecutorService`.

How can I still allow tasks to submit subtasks when the `ExecutorService` is shutting down?

Comment: You can't - so you need to find a way to shutdown after the last subtask has been submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you called shutdown, you shouldn't submit any new tasks, it's against the logic. 
Use a different executor service for the inner tasks. Or create an executor for yourself (that wraps or extends an executor of your choice) that is capable of checking the submitter and based on its state it either allows or not allows the task submission.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ForkJoinPool`, which is also an `ExecutorService`. From within ForkJoinTasks, you can call `ForkJoinPool.fork()` instead of the standard `execute()`. When shutting down, fork()s are still be allowed while execute()s are not. However, due to various other differences in behavior, `ForkJoinPool` might not be suitable for the task at hand (multiple queues instead of one, work-stealing, etc.)
Take a look at the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html